# Convergence in total variation to Gaussian implies finite moments?

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose $d_\mathrm{TV}(\mathbb{P}_n,\mathcal{N}(0,1)) \to 0$ for a sequence  of probability distributions $\mathbb{P}_n$. Is each $k^{th}$ moment of $\mathbb{P}_n$ necessarily finite after some $n_k$?

If yes, does each sequence of moments necessarily converge to the moments of $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Example: $\mathbb{P}_n=\frac{1}{n} Q + \left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right) \mathcal{N} $ where $Q$ is a Cauchy and $\mathcal{N}=\mathcal{N}(0,1)$.

Let $B$ be any Borel set. $|\mathbb{P}_n(B)-\mathcal{N}(B)|=\frac{1}{n}|Q(B)-\mathcal{N}(B)| \leq \frac{1}{n}$.

$d_\mathrm{TV}(\mathbb{P}_n,\mathcal{N})=\sup_B |\mathbb{P}_n(B)-\mathcal{N}(B)| \to 0$

Comment: Does $P_n$ converge in total variation? I would think not since for every n, the $P_n$-measure of the interval (-1/n,1/n) is far away from Normal. Thus the total variation distance does not converge to $0$. What am I missing?

Comment: I edited my answer with an argument, let me know if I am the one missing something!

Comment: Yes you are right. For some reason, I thought of this example before but managed to confused myself in believing it was false!